# Deciding between get_dummies and LabelEncoder for categorical variables in a Linear Regression Model

Tags: categorical-data, linear-model, scikit-learn, pandas

I'm using the dataset http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/airq402.dat whose description is here - http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/airq402.txt.

I'm planning to build a linear regression model with [Average Fare] as the dependent variable and all others as independent variables. The values in city columns and airline columns are categorical in nature.

What is the recommended way to convert the categorical variables in order to make them usable in the Linear Regression model - `get_dummies` (which transforms the values to columns and data as 0/1) or scikit-learn's `LabelEncoder` which just converts text values to numbers?

**My analysis on which one to use:**

Using the numbers from `LabelEncoder` doesn't give any real meaning to the converted data (i.e. the converted numbers are not really depicting the cities in some way). So, I'm tilting towards `get_dummies`.

Using `get_dummies` give a presence/absence but I find it difficult/awkward to use for a large number of values. Also, when two different city columns have same values, they are converted with same name. What is the best way to use get_dummies for variables with large number of values, and how to handle duplicate across columns?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem , get_dummies is the option to go with as it would give equal weightage to the categorical variables.
LabelEncoder is used when the categorical variables are ordinal i.e. if you are converting severity or ranking, then LabelEncoding "High" as 2 and "low" as 1 would make sense.
Also you would need to drop one dummy variable in each one of the converted columns to avoid dummy variable trap.

Coming to your second question, if you have two columns with the same city name then I am assuming they must have high correlation , did you do a chi-square test on them. If they are correlated then only use one of them.